# Is there a good way to prevent a server from emailing a specific address (we control both servers/apps)?

Tags: centos, email, firewall

When testing a production app we occasionally need to pull from a live site and perform tests on a development server.

There are quite a few email addresses stored in the database that we need to modify every time we restore to the development server. Occasionally someone on my team will miss one and accidentally send an email through the distribution list. The email looks legit because it is coming from a clone, it can cause quite the situation.

We have a protocol we follow every time we clone the live app and it has helped a lot but I would feel better if it was impossible for the two servers to communicate. Is there a good way to do this? Can firewall rules block email? Does Plesk have a blacklist?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you saying that you don't want the "test" server to be able to send emails? If so, then block outbound SMTP connections in the firewall or disable the email server service/process.

Comment: I'd also programmatically (write a shell script) sanitize any production data before putting it into development; I'd be removing/modifying all of the email addresses as part of that.

Comment: I just want to prevent the dev from being able to email a production address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two machines must stay identical, block the clone from sending email out on the network layer, i.e. in a firewall.

Comment: Specifically, block outbound TCP port 25, used for SMTP.

Comment: Will they still try to send and be Visible in a queue in case I need to see them? Would it make more sense to block incoming on production from the dev IP?

Comment: Yes, the server will try to send, and see the destination is not reachable. The message will be retried for as long as you have configured it to, and then bounced.

Answer (score 1):

Most email servers can be configured run in queue only mode.  If you also disable the queue runner process, mail will be accepted but not delivered.  You can check for outgoing messages by examining the queue.

If you know the email addresses you don't want to sent email to, you could create aliases that drop the messages. Exim uses a target of `:blackhole:` to do this.  You may need to configure the mail server to include or ignore the domain name in the alias lookup.

Disabling the mail system listener may work, but some programs invoke sendmail directly and don't need a listener.  This may annoy your programs though, and some may try to find a working relay server.

Blocking outbound traffic on port 25 using iptables is another option. This will annoy your mail server though.  It will retry transmissions, and eventually try to return your messages.

Automating the cleanup in combination with one of the above would be the best approach.